# Redux Form initial values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

Trying to initialize redux-form with initial values but getting error

> deleteIn.js:56 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'prizeId' in 0

Here is my part of code (generating Field Array )

```
<Field
    className="form-group"
    form="createChallenge"
    name={`${item}.prizeId`} -> here error comes
    valueField='value'
    textField='label'
    component={DropdownSelect}
    data={fetchedPrizes}
/>
```

Using react-widgets.

Hope your help

Comment: Can you post the code where you initialize the `item` data?

Answer (score 0):

The initial values key must be same with the field property name. Also you may forgot to pass `enableReinitialize="true"` in props along with inital value